# Java DecimalFormat include all digits to the left

Tags: java, numbers, formatting

I'm trying to format an arbitrary length decimal so all of the numbers to the left of the decimal point are displayed but a maximum of 2 to the right are displayed (if they are non-zero). How can I specify in a DecimalFormat to display all numbers to the left rather than specifying the number of digits ahead of time?

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help you

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

inputs/outputs:

```
System.out.println(formatter.format(-1234.567));         
System.out.println(formatter.format(1239.00));                
System.out.println(formatter.format(567));
System.out.println(formatter.format(0.2342523));
```

gave

```
-1234.57
1239
567
0.23
```

Comment: thanks. didn't realize the one # on the left side would get all the numbers. i probably should have just tried it. appreciate the quick help.